# How to get all fb profile links using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get all the links of users who liked my post

```
userName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="reaction_profile_browser"]/div[2]')
print(userName.text[0])
```

this gives me only one user output name.

any suggestions Guys?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want name try this:

```
#locate message form by_xpath

userName = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="reaction_profile_browser"]/div/div/div/div[1]')
userUrl = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="reaction_profile_browser"]/div/div/div/a')

#locate message form by_xpath
urlList = []
myUsers =[]


for element in range(len(userUrl)):


    urlList.append(userUrl[element].get_attribute("href"))
    myUsers.append(userName[element].text)

    print userName[element].text
    print userUrl[element].get_attribute("href")


# dictionary of lists  
dict = {'Username': myUsers, 'Url': urlList}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: how to remove add friends and make a list of all user name or is it possible to get only user name ?

Comment: check now @Gaurav